# Reading LLVM IR from a std::istream

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

Previously I had asked how to write then read back IR to/from a file.  The read code looked like:

```
LLVMContext ctx;
SMDiagnostic diag;
Module *m = ParseIRFile( "my_file", diag, ctx );
```

However, the code I'm trying to retrofit LLVM IR into passes me just a `std::istream&`.  How can I read IR from a `std::istream`?

I figured out how to use `raw_os_ostream` to adapt a `std::ostream` to a `raw_ostream` for writing a module, but there's no obvious way to adapt the code for reading, e.g., no `MemoryBuffer` that adapts a `std::istream` (unless I missed it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ParseIR()` instead of `ParseIRFile()`. It gets a `MemoryBuffer` as parameter, instead of a file name. You can create a `MemoryBuffer` from a `StringRef` via its `getMemBuffer()` factory method:

```
/// getMemBuffer - Open the specified memory range as a MemoryBuffer.  Note
/// that InputData must be null terminated if RequiresNullTerminator is true.
static MemoryBuffer *getMemBuffer(StringRef InputData,
                                  StringRef BufferName = "",
                                  bool RequiresNullTerminator = true);
```

And since a `StringRef` can be (even implicitly) constructed from an `std::string`, all you need to do is [convert your `std::istream` to `std::string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816319/reading-directly-from-an-stdistream-into-an-stdstring).

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. While it is apparently the only viable answer, it would be better if you could pass an `istream` to `ParseIR()` directly so as not to have to continually grow the `string`.