# How do I read bytes from file? C++

Tags: c++, file

On my desktop I have .txt file. I need to read all bytes from memory to array.

I tried to read text from file to string and then using memcpy() read bytes from string but I think this is not correct.

Tnx.

```
ifstream File("C:\\Users\\Flone\\Desktop\\ass.txt");
string file_text;
//start to read TEXT file (look end below):
char word_buffer[30];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    word_buffer[i] = NULL;
}
while (File.eof() == false)
{
    File >> word_buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        if (word_buffer[i] != NULL)
        {
            file_text += word_buffer[i];
        }
    }
    if (File.eof()==false) file_text += " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        word_buffer[i] = NULL;
    }
}
File.close();
//end read TEXT file.
cout << file_text << endl;
```

It works but I'm reading bytes from my string and not file or is it the same?

Comment: "I tried " ... let show this code

Comment: Indeed - what is going wrong when you try? [idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: @hlt I added code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816319/reading-directly-from-an-stdistream-into-an-stdstring

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Don't use `operator>>` for binary files.  Read up on `istream::read` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mini example using vector

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
```

this reads bytes from file into vector

```
    std::ifstream input("d:\\testinput.txt", std::ios::binary);

    std::vector<char> bytes(
         (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input)),
         (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    input.close();
```

Comment: Why do you need to wrap the iterators in parenthesis? My code does not compile when they are not included but I am not sure why.

Comment: @JacobSchneider a similar question was asked in the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912520/read-file-contents-into-a-string-in-c. In that case, the response was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse.