# How to create a std::string directly from a char* array without copying?

Tags: c++, string, stl, buffer

Say I have an array of chars, which I have allocated on the heap, and which I want to convert into an std::string. Currently I am doing the following:

```
char *array = new char[size];
WriteIntoArray(array, size);
std::string mystring(array);
delete[] array;
return mystring; // or whatever
```

From what I read on the internet (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), the string constructor performs a copy of the buffer I pass it, leaving me to free the buffer (later, the string frees its internal buffer). What I would like to do is to allocate my buffer, transfer control of it to the string, and then have it free my buffer when it is destructed.

The question [initializing std::string from char* without copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361500/initializing-stdstring-from-char-without-copy) looked promising, but my code relies on API calls ("WriteIntoArray" in the above example) which have to write into an array of chars, so I have to create a C-style char* buffer, and cannot convert my code to use only built-in string operations (which was the answer suggested).

Is there some standard way to do this, or should I just write my own string class (ugh)? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using a conforming C++0x implementation, or one of the many C++ libraries that guarantee contiguous storage for `std::string`, then you can get a `char*` that points directly to the storage used by your `std::string`.

For example:

```
std::string mystring;
mystring.resize(size);
WriteIntoArray(&mystring[0], size);
return mystring;
```

You may have to think carefully about a null terminator, however.

Comment: No. reserve() reserves the space, but it does not belong to the string (yet). Accessing a[0] or a[1] is still UB. If you checkout size() it will still be zero. What you actual want is resize()

Comment: You can't use reserve(), you must use resize(). And then figure out a proper resize() after the call.

Comment: `reserve` needs to be `resize`.  What does "think carefully about a null terminator" really mean?  Are any guarantees made as to whether the array pointed to by `&mystring[0]` must be null-terminated?  Is `std::string` responsible for ensuring that such a terminator is there?  If `WriteIntoArray` writes a null terminator, should it be removed?  (I ask because I don't know what is guaranteed and required by `std::string`.)

Comment: Before C++0x, `std::string` is only responsible for producing a null terminator when invoking `c_str()`. I would imagine that it would "just work" without manually inserting a null terminator, but I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: Presumably `WriteIntoArray` puts on a null terminator, which would need to be removed after the call; you probably want to add `mystring.resize(size-1);` just before returning. If it doesn't add the null, then you should be using `vector<char>` instead of `string`.

Comment: We don't know where the null terminator will be. The original code copied a C string of any length.

Comment: Will this code works when size=10 and array="ab\0trash.." mystring.size() will be 10 instead of 2?

Comment: @RiaD: It will make the string length 10, yes; `std::string` can contain embedded NULs. So if `size` is a maximum, not an exact length, this could wouldn't be optimal.

Comment: My answer feels lonely even though it was first and the same as this :-(

Comment: Thanks for the responses! This feels nitpicky, but is it necessary for STL strings to be contiguous in memory? I thought I read somewhere that they didn't have to be, so writing into `&mystring[0]`, `mystring.data()`, etc. could technically not work? Someone correct me on this?

Comment: `&mystring[0]` is guaranteed to return a pointer to contiguous memory, but up until C++0x it wasn't guaranteed that `std::string` uses contiguous storage internally. If that seems like a pointless distinction, that's because it pretty much is. Virtually every standard library uses contiguous storage.

Comment: Okay, I think I will just go with that. I am using the STL that comes with MSVC so I think it should be okay.

Comment: Does the standard actually permit modifying the string buffer like this? Considering that `data()` returns a `const char *` (even in C++11), it seems to be a hack... even if the hack will probably work for all actual implementations.

Comment: @SørenLøvborg Yes, it is permitted in C++11. There's a lot of arcane wording around this, which pretty much boils down to it being illegal to modify the null terminator, and being illegal to modify anything through the data() or c_str() pointers, but valid through &str[0]. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14291203/5696

Answer (score 12):

You may implement your own std::allocator that instead of allocating new memory for your string, uses as the source the region you already have instantiated.

You should then instantiate your std::string using your allocator.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement

Comment: Cool idea, totally forgot about allocators.

Answer (score 6):

You can't std::string owns the pointer and thus copies the data into a space that it allocates.

What you could do is:

```
std::string  mystring(size, ' ');
WriteIntoArray(&mystring[0], size);
return mystring; // or whatever
```