# Should I use std::string or Windows data types with DirectX?

Tags: c++, windows, string, winapi, directx

I have been working now on a project based on DirectX and I am struggling with something. Though the DirectX SDK relies heavily on Windows data types like `LPSTR`, `LPCSTR`, ... I have been using for my own classes `std::string` which was quite easy to work with, but it looks strange to mix both ways of handling strings. Although this is a vague question, what do you suggest - should I work with the `string`s or with the Windows pointers for different string types to keep some consistency?

Comment: `std::string` is by far easier to work with, and access to the underlying C string is only a few extra characters. That said, it's a bit more of a bother to use to interface with C in C++03 than it is in C++11.

Comment: I suggest using `std::wstring` on windows. See [std::wstring VS std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring).

Comment: Please read: http://www.utf8everywhere.org/#how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LPSTR` is just an alias for `char*` and `LCPSTR` is an alias for `const char*`, so your question actually sounds like *"Should I use C++ strings or C strings?"*

Well, C++ `std::string` has a member function called `c_str()` (or the equivalent `data()` function for STL compatibility) that returns a (non-modifiable) C string. So any time a function accepts an `LPCTSTR`, you can provide the output of `c_str()` as an argument.

I suggest you working with C++ `std::string` whenever you can, it is safer.

Comment: For completeness sake, `.data()` or `&str[0]` to get `char*`.

Comment: @Rapptz: writing to the buffer returned by `data()` and `c_str()` is UB though. Also, to the best of my knowledge, they both return `const char*`

Comment: I know that the Windows data types are just C strings yet I wanted to see how other people handle this mix of "real C++" code and these historical relicts used throughout the WinAPI. Thanks though for your suggestion.

Comment: @AndyProwl `&str[0]` is what I'm used to. i.e. `char* str2 = &str[0];`. I admit I'm not sure if `data()` returns a `const char*` or a `char*`.

Comment: @AndyProwl: What are your thought on using `std::wstring` rather than `std::string`? Jesse Good suggested this in a comment to my question.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: Jesse's suggestion is valid, but you have mentioned explicitly `LPSTR` and `LPCSTR`. Those are the `char`-based definitions. You could not pass the output of `wstring::c_str()` to a function accepting an `LPCSTR` without a conversion. But if your API accepts an `LPWSTR` and `LPCWSTR` instead, or if it accepts and `LPTSTR` and your project is using Unicode characters, then definitely use `std::wstring`, as the Windows OS is working with Unicode strings, so most of the times a conversion would be performed anyway.

Comment: @Rapptz, I hope [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290795/why-is-modifying-a-string-through-a-retrieved-pointer-to-its-data-not-allowed) helps clear up some missing knowledge in that area. You can use `&str[0]` to modify the buffer as long as you don't bump into the null terminator, and `data()` and `c_str()` are equivalent. Also note that all of this ease only comes with C++11, where string buffers have to have contiguous characters.

Answer (score 2):

In modern C++ code, I would just use a **robust string class** like `std::string`, or better `std::wstring` for **Unicode** UTF-16 support with Windows. Then, you can convert to "raw" C strings *at the API boundaries*.

To get a *read-only* "raw" C string pointer, you can use `std::[w]string::c_str()` method.

Instead, if you want to *modify* `std::[w]string` buffer, you can first call the `.resize()` method to prepare the string buffer, making it big enough; then you can use `&str[0]` to access the internal buffer for those APIs than need to write into it.

Note that on Windows specific code, ATL's `CString` is another convenient string class you may want to use. It has some platform-specific convenient facilities, like loading string from resources (which is good for app localization).

Since `CString` offers an implicit conversion to `LPCTSTR`, you can just pass `CString` instances to APIs expecting a raw `LPCTSTR`. Instead, if you need to modify the internal `CString` buffer, you can use `GetBuffer()`/`ReleaseBuffer()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Andy Prowl's answer, you might want to code everything using "T" strings (i.e. `LPTSTR` instead of `LPSTR` or `LPWSTR`). The exact type of T (really `TCHAR`) is set at compile time based on whether you have `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` `#defined`. This gives you compatibility with both.

You can still use C++ strings with this technique by deriving a `tstring` class from `basic_string<>`:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```

Comment: On modern Win32 C++ code, I'd just use UTF-16 on Windows (UTF-8 is OK outside app boundaries), and just use `std::wstring` and `wchar_t` (or `CString` in Unicode builds, corresponding to `CStringW`), instead of the old ANSI/MBCS-compatible `TCHAR` model. I consider the `TCHAR` model something obsolete and useless in modern days.

Comment: Good point. +1. But speaking of modern days, what about Win32 and DirectX? Haven't newer languages (C#) and APIs (WPF) passed them by, too? BTW, the irony of @Mr.C64 talking about obsolescence is not lost on me. :)

Comment: Saying `Passed them by` doesn't make sense because those newer technologies are built on top of the older ones. They are still in great use today. However, `TCHAR` has little use other than for old code bases or backwards compatibility.

Comment: Ouch! Don't use TCHAR. Not unless you need to support Windows 98.