# Why shouldn't I use std::string.c_str() as a buffer?

Tags: c++, stdstring

While this may well be a stupid question, I saw something about how you shouldn't do this, despite the fact that it is allowed in C++ 11, but I don't quite get why. Could anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290795/why-is-modifying-a-string-through-a-retrieved-pointer-to-its-data-not-allowed)?

Comment: Well it's `const` – is an immutable buffer useful to you?

Comment: It is **not** allowed in C++11.

Comment: It might be confusing to someone who has to maintain the code.

Comment: @juanchopanza : Using `std::string` as a buffer is allowed in C++11, just by way of `&str[0]` rather than `str.c_str()`.

Comment: @ildjarn, As long as you don't overwrite the null character.

Comment: @ildjarn the question is about using `std::string::c_str()` as a buffer.

Comment: In response to those stating how it's const, and therefore unusable, it seems to work fine in several cases. @Chris, thanks for the article, that didn't come up for the searches.

Comment: @RT_34, Undefined behaviour seems to work fine in many cases. In a couple of months, it then doesn't.

Comment: @chris : Right, the valid buffer range is `[0,s.size())`, just as with a `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: OK, thanks, that makes sense. Because I prefer working with std::strings to C-style strings, is there any way to actually use a string as a buffer, for instance in Win32 SendMessage?

Comment: @RT_34, Yes, it's been mentioned: `&str[0]` and don't let it overwrite the null.

Comment: But surely another null would be added from the message? EDIT: Ignore this, I just remembered something about how memory for stings is concurrent, and this would mess up. Therefore, I should defines string str[10], and call it via &str[0]?

Comment: @RT_34: What should add `0` to the string? How should the string know that it's interior has been changed? Therefore _you_ have the responsibility to keep the string valid if you use it as a `std::string` again.

Comment: Just a personal preference, but for a buffer, I prefer `std::vector<char>` to `std::string`.

Comment: @James : Of course if you eventually want the data in a `std::string`, that will involve copying all of the data, since one cannot transfer ownership of a `std::vector<char>`'s buffer into a `std::string`. Fortunately this will become a non-issue once `string_ref` becomes standardized.

Comment: @ildjarn Good point, although if you're interfacing to legacy C code, it's probably that the function you're calling will do enough to make the time for the extra copy irrelevant.  But I'll admit that my attitude may be out of date; when I started dealing with such problems, there was still active discussion about string implementations which didn't keep their data in a contiguous block.  Now, of course... C++11 requires it (I think).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's not allowed!**

> ### 21.4.7 basic_string string operations[string.ops]
>
> #### 21.4.7.1 basic_string accessors[string.accessors]
>
> ```
> const charT* c_str() const noexcept;
> const charT* data() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> 1. Returns: A pointer p such that p + i == &operator for each i in [0,size()].
> 2. Complexity: constant time.
> 3. Requires: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.

Other than that, you're modifying data references by a `const char *`, which usually indicates a `const_cast<char*>`. Not only will this result in undefined behaviour, but according to Herb Sutter `const` should be read as thread-safe nowadays ([see his talk about `const` and `mutable`](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank)).

However, as it has been stated, the use of `std::string str; &str[0]` is safe if `str` is sufficiently large. Just don't use `.c_str()` or `.data()`.

Comment: The `const_cast` will cause undefined behavior only when a) casting away const-ness of an object that is const (rather than a reference that is const) and b) it is used to modify the object. The second part would be true, the first one depends on whether the string on which `c_str()` is called is const or not (and even if it is const, it might be that the buffer is still not const...). That being said, the better approach is using `&str[0]`