# How to add integer to LPWSTR

Tags: c++, function, unicode, int, concatenation

I have a function that takes only one `LPWSTR` as argument. However, I need to add integer to the end of it.

Here's an example pseudocode:

```
int theNumber = 5;
LPWSTR myLPWSTR = L"Number is: ";
/* Add theNumber to myLPWSTR */
myFunction(myLPWSTR);
```

How to do this?

I have already tried converting `int` to `LPWSTR` and then concatenate them but I didn't succeed. I've tried this for the whole morning but just can't figure out how to do this.

I've tried eg. wsprintf, _itow_s, c_str and pretty much everything I know of - but just can't do it and it's getting really frustrating.

Someone please help.

Comment: Can you post (some) code you've tried?

Comment: Be aware that you can't modify `myLPWSTR` because it points to constant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the function really takes a `LPWSTR` and not a `LPCWSTR` (i.e. it can modify the string passed in), you'll have to do something like this:

```
int theNumber = 5;
std::wostringstream s;
s << L"Number is: " << theNumber;
std::wstring str = s.str();
std::vector<wchar_t> buf(str.begin(), str.end());
buf.push_back(0);
myFunctions(&buf[0]);
```

This is necessary because you need to supply a properly nul-terminated and modifiable buffer of `wchar_t`s. `str.c_str()` is nul-terminated but not modifiable. `&str[0]` is modifiable but not (guaranteed to be) nul-terminated.

Comment: @chris Of course, thanks; edited. I originally had a `+ 1` in there, then decided to go with `push_back()` and didn't update it. Apparently you can get code smell even in an 8-line example.

Comment: Hehe :) And a small note on the last sentence only applying to pre-C++11. As of C++11, it's a valid C string and modifiable up to and not including the implicit null. Pre-C++11 also has the possible discontiguity.

Comment: @chris Do you have a quote for the C++11 stuff? All I could find is that `s[s.size()]` references a `NUL`, and that `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` holds for `0 <= n < s.size()`.

Comment: That's both the implicit null and contiguity right there, but you might find my related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290795/why-is-modifying-a-string-through-a-retrieved-pointer-to-its-data-not-allowed) helpful.

Comment: @chris Thanks, I think I get it now. I was just confused by the fact that it does not (explicitly) require `&*(s.begin() + s.size()) == &*s.begin() + s.size()` to hold.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use **C++11**:

```
std::wstring str = L"Number is: ";
str += std::to_wstring(42);
myFunction( str.data() );
```

if not:

```
std::wstringstream ss;
ss << L"Number is: " << 42;
myFunction( ss.str().c_str() );
```

Don't forget to include *string* and *sstream*.

Comment: Not if the function takes a `LPWSTR`. You have to use `&str[0]` and not let it modify the implicit null. Note that this method only works for C++11 and up. Also note that `data()` is equivalent to `c_str()` in C++11.

Comment: This would be short and good, but I got an error: error C2664: 'myFunction' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'LPWSTR' . I will check now the other suggestions, thank you :)

Comment: Does your function have to take LPWSTR ? can you not change it to LPCWSTR ? If not, use Angews version to copy the new string in a vector and use that.

Comment: What headers do I need to include for Visual Studio to recognise "std"?