# Do c_str()'s requirements make modification illegal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

My copy of a draft C++ standard (labelled "ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N3690
Date: 2013-05-15") has the following definition for `basic_string::c_str()` and `basic_string::data()`.

> ```
> const charT* c_str() const noexcept; 
> const charT* data() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> Returns: A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for
>   each `i` in `[0,size()]`.
>
> Complexity: constant time.
>
> Requires: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.

It appears, then, that the following C++ program has undefined behaviour, as it trips over the requirement from `c_str()`:

```
#include <string>
int main() {
  std::string foo = "foo";
  foo.c_str();
  foo[2] = 'p';
}
```

This seems breathtakingly stupid.  Have I misread the standard, or is this requirement on `c_str` a relic from a bygone era?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is modifying a string through a retrieved pointer to its data not allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290795/why-is-modifying-a-string-through-a-retrieved-pointer-to-its-data-not-allowed)

Comment: @Pradhan: Nice find.  But the answer to that question states that modifying the string via the `&foo[0]` pointer is perfectly valid, which, from the plain language of the standard, it isn't.  I shot the answerer a comment to that effect.

Comment: Not sure if there are some guidelines to reading the standard which would enforce the interpretation that modifying it via `&foo[0]` is valid. I agree that the wording supports your interpretation. At least according to my interpretation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular phrasing is a relic from the C++03-era specification that permitted copy-on-write strings. At [some point in the past](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2521.pdf) the spec for `c_str()` read:

> *Returns*: A pointer to the initial element of an array of length
>   `size() + 1` whose first `size()` elements equal the corresponding
>   elements of the string controlled by `*this` and whose last element is
>   a null character specified by `charT()`.
>
> *Requires*: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the array. Nor shall the program treat the returned value as a valid
>   pointer value after any subsequent call to a non-`const` member
>   function of the class `basic_string` that designates the same object as
>   `this`.

in which context the requirement made a lot more sense. If `c_str()` returned a pointer to a string shared between different `std::string`s, modifying the values in the array would be really bad.

In C++14, this prohibition makes very little sense. Reading it as prohibiting modifying the string at all after a `c_str()` call won't make much sense, as you pointed out; reading it as prohibiting modifying the `string` through the returned pointer would make slightly more sense, but not much. There's no real reason why the semantics should be different between the pointer returned by `c_str()` and the pointer obtained using `&operator[](0)`.

Comment: OK.  I gather that this is nonsense and that I should learn how to file a defect report?  (And that this has always been specified in a buggy way that assumed a particular uncommon implementation?)

Comment: @tmyklebu COW strings used to be pretty common in C++03 standard libraries. But yes, I think this is a defect.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is wrong.
The array pointed to by the char * returned should not be modified.

This isn't allowed

```
#include <string>
int main() 
{
    std::string foo = "foo";
    char * ptr = (char *)foo.c_str();
    ptr[2] = 'p'; // undefined
}
```

The original string can be modified but that will invalidate the return of `c_str`

Comment: Under "Returns:", it specifies that the pointer returned by `foo.c_str()` is equal (in the `==` sense) to the pointer returned by `&foo[0]`.  Thus my code is doing exactly what is forbidden.  Also, `c_str()` returns a `const char *`, not a `char *` as you state.

Comment: @tyklebu   It doesn't say that  foo.c_str() == &foo[0].    It says that foo.c_str()[0] == foo[0].   That allows c_str() and data() to create/manage a copy of the string contents, and return a pointer to the copy.

Comment: @Rob: No; `foo.c_str() == &foo[0]` is the special case `i = 0` of `c_str() + i == &foo[i]`.  Also, the copying business is forbidden because `c_str()` must take constant time.