# Using &front() to modify underlying character array in std::string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have to interface with a C library in one of my programs, and I am writing a thin wrapper to use C++ types such as `std::string`. There are quite a number of functions that accept a `char*` and a maximum length as parameter and overwrite the memory pointed to by the `char*` with a zero-terminated C-string. Traditionally, I used a stack array and copied the data into a string manually.

```
std::string call_C_function(int x) {
    char buf[MAX_LEN] = {0}; // MAX_LEN is defined by the library
    size_t len = MAX_LEN;
    C_function(x, buf, &len);
    return std::string(buf, len);
}
```

I tried to avoid the copy and came up with a solution, but I don't know if this is strictly legal:

```
std::string call_C_function(int x) {
    std::string buf(MAX_LEN, '\0'); // MAX_LEN is defined by the library
    size_t len = MAX_LEN;
    C_function(x, &buf.front(), &len);
    buf.resize(len);
    return buf;
}
```

This compiles and works, but I am having doubts because the `std::string` class makes it quite hard to get a non-const pointer to the character data. `c_str()` and `data()` both return const pointers. The standard forbids modifications of the buffer explicitly for these functions:

> 21.4.7.1: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.

From the documentation, it seems that this is legal because `front()` returns a reference to the first character of the buffer which must be continuous (I am using C++11/14). In 21.4.5, the semantics of `front()` is defined in terms of `operator[](0)` which does not forbid modifications.

Are there any issues with this approach from a language standard point of view? It seems that this would be a loop-hole allowing the modification explicitly forbidden in 21.4.7.1.

Comment: My [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290795/why-is-modifying-a-string-through-a-retrieved-pointer-to-its-data-not-allowed) might help you there.

Comment: Your function can just use a `std::vector<char>` and thus skip the doubts in using `std::string` directly..

Comment: @chris Should have read the last paragraph... I think it answers my question

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I could use a `vector<char>`, but the function returns a string which should be a std::string.

Comment: @Jens You could do a `return buf.data();` for `std::vector`, and it will work correctly if the return is a `std::string`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am not sure I understand. In your case, `buf` is a `std::vector<char>`. But the return will first allocate memory in the return string, and then copy the data into it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, but why would you want to do two allocations and two copies? The OP's code is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my read of C++11:

> const charT& front() const;
>
> charT& front();
>
> Requires: !empty()
>
> Effects: Equivalent to operator[](0).

Let's look at operator[]:

> const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
>
> reference operator[](size_type pos);
>
> 1 Requires: pos <= size().
>
> 2 Returns: *(begin() + pos) if pos < size(), otherwise a reference to
>   an object of type T with valuecharT(); the referenced value shall not be modified.

Since you preallocate your buffer, `pos` will be less than size(). begin() returns an iterator, so all the usual iterator traits apply.

So, according to my interpretation of C++11, this approach should be legal.

Comment: That basically my understanding as well, but I am wondering if there is something I overlooked because this seems to be a loophole to do what `data()` explicitly forbids.

Comment: But `data()` is a const function. It makes sense that you aren't allowed to modify the characters by getting a pointer from a const function (what if the entire string is const?). You are not calling a const function, and you are not trying to modify a const string. There is no problem. The standard does not forbid modification of strings!

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ok, so the part only states that I am not allowed to modify data through the const pointer explicitly. I took this for granted and read it as a more general constraint to not modify the character array bypassing the member functions for this.

Comment: No, it's a constraint _on those functions_ not on strings in general.

Answer (score 4):

This is fine. You aren't allowed to modify the string via a pointer returned from a `const` member function but that doesn't mean you aren't allowed to modify the string at all. You have a non-const string, so you can modify it. In principle it's no different to doing `s[0] = 'a'; s[1] = 'b';` etc.

It is forbidden to overwrite the final `'\0'` that is stored after the string data, but I assume from your example that `MAX_LEN` includes the space for the null terminator that is written by the C function, so the C function will only overwrite the string contents and not the extra character stored afterwards.

There is an open issue ([LWG 2391](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2391)) proposing to add a non-const `std::string::data()` which would be equivalent to `&s.front()`, and would give you direct access without making you concerned about going against the intention of the library.