# Passing pointer to first string element as buffer

Tags: c++

I have a bunch of old linux code which does something like this:

```
int size_of_buffer = /*stuff computed dynamically*/;
char *buffer = malloc(size_of_buffer);
recv(socket, buffer, size_of_buffer, 0);
//do some processing of the buffer as string
free(buffer);
```

When I was migrating it to C++ I changed it like this:

```
int size_of_buffer = /*stuff computed dynamically*/;
const auto buffer = make_unique<char[]>(size_of_buffer);
recv(socket, buffer.get(), size_of_buffer, 0);
const std::string str_buffer = buffer.get();
//do some processing on str_buffer
```

Which you can't fail to notice causes double memory allocation and potentially multiple copying of data. My idea now is to pass the pointer to first character of the `std::string` with `reserve`d storage, like this:

```
int size_of_buffer = /*stuff computed dynamically*/;
std::string buffer;
buffer.reserve(size_of_buffer);
recv(socket, &(buffer[0]), size_of_buffer, 0);
//do some processing on buffer
```

Is above code safe and well defined or there are some caveats and dangers that need to be avoided?

Comment: i'd use '[buffer.data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)`

Comment: @Thomas I have my doubts due to fact that `data()` is `const`

Comment: What c++-version are you on?

Comment: @bartop There is a non-const version since C++17. However, `data()` only guarantees a valid range from `data()` (inclusive) to `data + size()` (exclusive according to cppreference, but inclusive according to [latest draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.accessors-1)): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data. `reserve()` alone won't help I fear.

Comment: Since c++11, your `&(buffer[0])` is equivalent to `buffer.data()` see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). Furhermore, "Modifying the character array accessed through the const overload of data has undefined behavior.", so if you are below C+17, what you are doing is UB regardless how you do it.

Comment: @n314159 that sounds like an answer, anyway, how can I avoid coping data pre C++17?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361500/initializing-stdstring-from-char-without-copy) may help you. (aka, I don't think it is possible). Maybe you could do something by providing a custom allocator, but that is not worth the trouble. If you provide more information on what you want to do with the string, maybe we can find a workaround.

Comment: @MaxLanghof if I filled the string with some data, it would be valid or there still would be something wrong?

Comment: In c++17, if you `resize` the string, everything should be fine. (Or just construct it with the right size)

Comment: Beware that `const std::string str_buffer = buffer.get()` will only work if `buffer` has a null character in it. The right way to do that would be with `const std::string str_buffer(buffer.get(), lengh_returned_by_recv)`.

Comment: @n314159 I would be grateful if you compiled it into an answer, some people may have same problem and overlook the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361500/initializing-stdstring-from-char-without-copy). The short answer is: it is not possible without copying.

Below C++17, there is no non-`const` overload of [`std::string::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), and

> 1) Modifying the character array accessed through the const overload of `data` has undefined behavior.

Hence, you cannot modify the string through `data`.

Since C++11,

> `data() + i == std::addressof(operator[](i))` for every `i` in `[0, size()]`.

Therefore, you also cannot modify the string through `&(buffer[0])`.

Before C+11, it is actually not very clear to me, what exactly is allowed, so maybe modifying through `&(buffer.begin())` is ok, but I don't think so.

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), there is actually a quote that confounds me a bit

> The elements of a basic_string are stored contiguously, that is, for a `basic_string s`, `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` for any `n` in `[0, s.size())`, or, equivalently, a pointer to `s[0]` can be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the first element of a (null-terminated (since C++11)) `CharT[]` array.

I think this means to `const` array, since otherwise it would not fit to the rest of the documentation and right now I do not have the time to go through the standard.

Since C++17, your code is ok, if you use [`std::string::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) instead of `reserve`, since `data()` only guarantees a valid range on `[data(), data() + size())` (or you can just construct the string with the right size). There is no-non-copy way to create a string from a `char *`.

You can use a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), which has a constant constructor from `char *`. It does exactly what you want here, since it has no ownership on the pointer and memory.